# Refresh Filter AutoComplete when grid datasource is refreshed

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a grid with filter row mode enabled. 
filters are either drop down lists, or autocomplete fields. When the grid is first initialized, the autocompletes are initialized correctly with their list of possible suggestions based on the data present in the grid (server side filtering is not enabled). I have search button which changes the datasource of the grid and refreshes the data.

```
 <kendo-grid k-options="vm.mainGridOptions"
                                                k-columns="vm.mainGridColumns"
                                                k-sortable="true"
                                                k-filterable="{mode: 'row'}"
                                                k-column-menu="true"
                                                k-serverFiltering="false"
                                                k-pageSize="10"
                                                k-pageable="{ pageSizes: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100] }">
                                    </kendo-grid>
```

When I do this, the grid is updated and the new data set like i want. However, it seems that the autocomplete filter field values are based on the old grid and don't reflect the new data.

```
vm.mainGridColumns = [
        {
            field: "customerName",
            title: "Name",
            filterable: { multi: true, search: true }, 
            template:
                "<a ui-sref='resiservice.account-search.customer-details({ customerId:${customerId}, serviceAccountId:${serviceAccountId} })'>${customerName}</a>"
        },
        {
            field: "serviceAccountStatus",
            filterable: {
                multi: true, search: true
            },
            title: "Status"
        },
        {
            field: "customerNumber",
            filterable: { multi: true, search: true },
            title: "NAP Customer #"
        }];
```

Comment: Hi can anyone help me on this, i am still looking for solution.